# Remove classes from wc_get_product_cat_class Woocommerce Function

Tags: php, woocommerce

The `wc_get_product_cat_class` function in Woocommerce wc-template-functions.php adds the classes 'first' and 'last' to some of my `<li>` elements.

I would like to remove those classes. Does anyone know how I can overwrite this in my functions.php without editing the actual Woocommerce functions?

I've searched everywhere but can't find any solutions. I'm still pretty new at this, hopefully this isn't too much of a dumbass question :/

Below is the function from wc-template-functions.php

```
function wc_get_product_cat_class( $class = '', $category = null ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    $classes   = is_array( $class ) ? $class : array_map( 'trim', explode( ' ', $class ) );
    $classes[] = 'product-category';
    $classes[] = 'product';

    if ( 0 === ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] - 1 ) % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] || 1 === $woocommerce_loop['columns'] ) {
        $classes[] = 'first';
    }

    if ( 0 === $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] ) {
        $classes[] = 'last';
    }

    $classes = apply_filters( 'product_cat_class', $classes, $class, $category );

    return array_unique( array_filter( $classes ) );
}
```

And this is the code from content-product_cat.php template that calls the function

```
<li <?php wc_product_cat_class( '', $category ); ?>>
    <?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_subcategory hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_category_link_open - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory', $category );

    /**
     * woocommerce_before_subcategory_title hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', $category );

    /**
     * woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_category_title - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', $category );

    /**
     * woocommerce_after_subcategory_title hook.
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', $category );

    /**
     * woocommerce_after_subcategory hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_category_link_close - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory', $category ); ?>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delayed but thought this may help. You can define your own wc_product_cat_class function and call it from content-product_cat.php

For example:
If you want to remove the "first" and "last" class, you can use the code below.

```
function your_own_wc_product_cat_class( $class = '', $category = null ) {
    $product_cat_classes = array_diff( wc_get_product_cat_class( $class, $category ), array( 'first', 'last' ) );
    echo 'class="' . esc_attr( join( ' ', $product_cat_classes ) ) . '"';
}
```

Now you can call this from content-product_cat.php like this `<?php ro_wc_product_cat_class() ?>`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's kinda too late but hopefully someone will need it too...

```
if (  ! function_exists( 'YOUR_product_cat_class' ) ) {

    function YOUR_product_cat_class( $class = '', $category = null ) {

        // this one is Toast grid based, I use it in my own theme
        $classes[] = 'grid__col';
        $wc_span = 12 / apply_filters( 'loop_shop_columns', 4 );
        $spans = array( 6, 4, 3, 2 );
        $span  = in_array( $wc_span, $spans ) ? $wc_span : 4;
        $classes[] = 'grid__col--' . $span . '-of-12';

        return array_unique( array_filter( $classes ) );

    }

}
add_filter( 'product_cat_class' , 'YOUR_product_cat_class' );
```

On a side note, be sure to edit your `content-product_cat.php` template properly. For instance, I don't use unordered list and my loop starts with DIV instead (`content-product_cat.php`, line #37):

```
<div <?php wc_product_cat_class( '', $category ); ?>>
```